# SQL Server rounding discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I have a rounding discrepancy in SQL that I could do with a hand resolving.

I have 2 SQL calculations, the first one equals 1.1 and the second 5.65 (see below)

```
round((sum((monthly_markup)+100) / 100) / sum(monthly_qty),2) as timesby, --equals 1.1
sum(monthly_buy)/sum(monthly_qty) as buy, -- equals 5.65
```

If I then take those calculations and do calc1 x calc2 it equals 6.21

```
cast (round(sum(monthly_buy)/sum(monthly_qty) * (sum((monthly_markup)+100) / 100) / sum(monthly_qty),2) as decimal (30,2)), -- equals 6.21 !!
```

But I am expecting 6.22, as per the below calculation

```
cast (round((5.65 * 1.1),2) as decimal (30,2)) -- equals 6.22
```

How can I get my calculation to return 6.22?

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of monthly_buy, monthly_qty and monthly_markup? What value do you get without rounding?

Comment: All datatypes are float. I removed the rounding and actually all the results are the same

Comment: If I remove the Cast to decimal(s), the answer are 6.215

Comment: Use FLOAT for calculation, and DECIMAL for storage.  DECIMAL arithmetic is prone to loss of precision in calculations, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Precision%20is%20the%20number%20of%20digits%20in%20a,of%20SQL%20Server,%20the%20default%20maximum%20is%2028.

Comment: @user3580480 what do you get if you do `round(sum(cast(monthly_buy as decimal(30,2)))/sum(cast(monthly_qty as decimal(10,2))) * (sum((cast(monthly_markup as decimal(10,2)))+100) / 100) / sum(cast(monthly_qty as decimal(10,2))), 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, I resolved by casting the sum of buy * qty to decimal first.

```
round((cast(sum(monthly_buy)/sum(monthly_qty) as decimal (5,3)) * round((sum((monthly_markup)+100) / 100) / sum(monthly_qty),2)),2)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for you. If you have the ability to mark your own question answered, please do that. That way, users can see that your question was successfully answered.

Comment: Thank you, I can only mark as answered in 2 days time